# Octopress Build Error

Tags: github, rake, blogs, octopress, build-error

I'm working on a post on my Octopress blog, and everything seems to be pushing up to my github account correctly.  However, when I run `rake generate`, I get the following email:

```
The page build failed with the following error:

The submodule `.themes/whitespace` was not properly initialized with a `.gitmodules` file.
```

This is preventing my last post from going live on the page. I've found a few responses that suggested deleting the file, but wouldn't that delete my theme?  Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some merge errors, that once fixed, still didn't work. So I went back to an old commit, and remade the post. After that everything works!